# Codeigniter 3 - Why my app is connecting to my database without loading it anywhere?

Tags: codeigniter

See this, i have commented database in autoload but it still connecting anyway...

`//$autoload['libraries'] = array('session','database','template','commun','form_validation');`

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('session','template','commun','form_validation');`

Answer (score 0):

that mean you are calling database in every controller

```
$this->load->database();
```